# Can an implicit converter have a by-name parameter?

Tags: scala

I want to simplify code of my ScalaTest suites.
Most of my tests have a body which produces some `Assertion`-s and then also needs to execute some cleanups, which conceptually are side-effects but in case some of these clean-ups produce an exception I want to fail the test with that exception.
So before I started to simplify the tests looked like one below:

```
"Admin" should "be able to create a new team" in{
    val attempt=Try{
      When("Admin opens the Teams view")
      TeamsPage.open
      And("creates a new team")
      TeamsPage.createNewTeam(tempTeam)
      Then("this team is shown in the list")
      TeamsPage.isParticularTeamShownInTeamList(tempTeam.name) shouldBe true
    }
    val cleanUp = Try(TeamsPage.cleanUpTeam(tempTeam))
    attempt.flatMap(r => cleanUp.map(_ => r)).get
}
```

Quite nice but I would like to have a bit less boilerplate. So I started from something like this:

```
class FollowUp(block: => Assertion){
  def andThen[T](followUp: =>T):Assertion = {
    val start = Try(block)
    val followUpAttempt = Try(followUp)
    start.flatMap(r => followUpAttempt.map(_ => r)).get
  }
}

object FollowUp{
  implicit def assertionToFollowUp(a: => Assertion):FollowUp = new FollowUp(a)
}


class TeamManagementTest extends ADMPSuite with AbilityToManageUsers{
  import FollowUp._

  val tempTeam = Team("Temp QA Team")

  "Admin" should "be able to create a new team" in{
    {
      When("Admin opens the Teams view")
      TeamsPage.open
      And("creates a new team")
      TeamsPage.createNewTeam(tempTeam)
      Then("this team is shown in the list")
      TeamsPage.isParticularTeamShownInTeamList(tempTeam.name) shouldBe false
    } andThen TeamsPage.cleanUpTeam(tempTeam)
  }
}
```

As you can see my idea was to start with a simple combinator `andThen` which would allow me to follow-up my test body with one side effect. I wanted to pass the test body by-name, so it does not start executing until it gets wrapped into `Try()`. This is needed because I need the followup side effect to execute even in case when test body fails or produces an error.
So I have declared an implicit converter which takes the by-name parameter.
But it does not compile and says me this:

```
Error:(49, 42) type mismatch;
 found   : Boolean
 required: PartialFunction[scala.util.Try[org.scalatest.compatible.Assertion],?]
    attempt andThen TeamsPage.cleanUpTeam(tempTeam)
                                         ^
```

I don't understand why this happens.
If I change the parameter to be by-value

```
object FollowUp{
  implicit def assertionToFollowUp(a: Assertion):FollowUp = new FollowUp(a)
}
```

then the code compiles but it does not of course apply the followup in case the test body fails or produces an exception.

Could you advice how to solve this problem in a nice way?

Comment: Although @ephemient solution is good and you probably should use it, it looks like you are interested in the root cause of your issue but I can't reproduce it using your example. If I fill in a bit simplified version of it with some stubs, it compiles for me (see [full code](https://pastebin.com/DdSuS3Tw) I tried). So could you please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Will try to extract MCVE tomorrow, though it might not be that easy :)

Comment: I got where the problem was. I renamed "andThen" to "followWith" and then it compiles and works as expected in both cases when test body produces successful assertions and when it fails. After thinking over that `PartialFunction` mentioned in the error has nothing to do with my case I realized that `andThen` is a method of `PartialFunction` so there should be some naming shadowing or something. So if I name the function whatever, even "alex" it works.

Comment: The error shows a symbol "attempt" which isn't in your second test. A complete example would be helpful. In fact, it makes a difference what sort of test suite you're constructing. PartialFunction.andThen takes a function, not a PF, which was a clue.

Comment: som-snytt, sorry, you are right and I am inattentive

Comment: som-snytt, I am extending my suite from `AsyncFlatSpec` so the clue was indeed not about `PartialFunction` but about `Future.andThen`. In `AsyncFlatSpec`  every test is expected to provied `Future[Assertion]` result so `andThen` was expected to be applied to such future and in that case argument is of `PartialFunction` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I described above in a comment the problem was in the name of the method `andThen`. It happened so that the same method is a member of `PartialFuction` class and in this case compiler decided that I am trying to invoke it on partial function. After I renamed the method everything compiled and worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use what ScalaTest calls the a loan-fixture:

```
def withTeamsPage[A](body: Team => A) = {
  val tempTeam = Team("Temp QA Team")
  try {
    body(tempTeam)
  } finally {
    TeamsPage.cleanUpTeam(tempTeam)
  }
}

"Admin" should "be able to create a new team" in withTeamsPage { tempTeam =>
  When("Admin opens the Teams view")
  TeamsPage.open
  And("creates a new team")
  TeamsPage.createNewTeam(tempTeam)
  Then("this team is shown in the list")
  TeamsPage.isParticularTeamShownInTeamList(tempTeam.name) shouldBe false   
}
```

Comment: ephemient, thanks for this suggestion. I will give it a try when will be at my laptop later. Not sure if it will suite because I just provided a sample of a simplest test. In my suites I have usually dozens of tests and some of them are quite complicated, initializing different entitities, using DB or API calls, etc. But anyway, this loan pattern I should use.
Meanwhile, do you have any ideas why by-name parameter in implicit convertor does not compile?

Comment: @AlexanderArendar Basically by the time you're trying to apply the conversions, you have a block (value) instead of a thunk (name). I find it hard to predict when which will happen :( https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3237

Comment: I have even tried to declare the block as lazy val but that does not help. Not sure that the block in the current snippet gets computed before the conversion takes place. As the code looks to me - it should compute only after conversion.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, but maybe something else is going on with your test.

I don't use ScalaTest except for one or two SO questions, so with a grain of salt:

```
package testy

import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scala.util.Try
import org.scalatest._
import Matchers._

trait Cleaner {
  def cleanUp(): Unit = println("cleaning...")
}

class FollowUp(block: => Assertion) {
  println("deferring...")
  def andThen[T](followUp: => T): Assertion = {
    println("evaluate...")
    val start = Try(block)
    println("followup...")
    val followUpAttempt = Try(followUp)
    start.flatMap(r => followUpAttempt.map(_ => r)).get
  }
}

object FollowUp{
  implicit def assertionToFollowUp(a: => Assertion): FollowUp = new FollowUp(a)
}

import FollowUp._

class CSpec extends FlatSpec with Cleaner {
  "A zero size Set" should "have size 0" in {
    assert(Set.empty.size == 0)
  }

  "An empty Set" should "have size 0" in {
    {
      println("test...")
      Set.empty.isEmpty shouldBe true
    } andThen cleanUp()
  }
}
```

Yields the output:

```
deferring...
evaluate...
test...
followup...
cleaning...
[info] CSpec:
[info] A zero size Set
[info] - should have size 0
[info] An empty Set
[info] - should have size 0
[info] Run completed in 233 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 2
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 2, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jun 2, 2017 5:11:16 PM
```

`-Xprint:typer` shows the conversion

```
    CSpec.this.convertToInAndIgnoreMethods(org.scalatest.Matchers.convertToStringShouldWrapper("An empty Set")(org.scalactic.source.Position.apply("CSpec.scala", "Please set the environment variable SCALACTIC_FILL_FILE_PATHNAMES to yes at compile time to enable this feature.", 34), scalactic.this.Prettifier.default).should("have size 0")(CSpec.this.shorthandTestRegistrationFunction)).in(FollowUp.assertionToFollowUp({
  scala.Predef.println("test...");
  org.scalatest.Matchers.convertToAnyShouldWrapper[Boolean](scala.Predef.Set.empty[Nothing].isEmpty)(org.scalactic.source.Position.apply("CSpec.scala", "Please set the environment variable SCALACTIC_FILL_FILE_PATHNAMES to yes at compile time to enable this feature.", 37), scalactic.this.Prettifier.default).shouldBe(true)
}).andThen[Unit](CSpec.this.cleanUp()))(org.scalactic.source.Position.apply("CSpec.scala", "Please set the environment variable SCALACTIC_FILL_FILE_PATHNAMES to yes at compile time to enable this feature.", 34))
```

This demonstrates the difference between converting result expression of a block to an expected type, and converting a block expression to a type that has a required member:

```
$ scala -language:_
Welcome to Scala 2.12.2 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> case class C(c: Int)
defined class C

scala> implicit def cc(i: => Int): C = C(42)
cc: (i: => Int)C

scala> 5.c
res0: Int = 42

scala> def f(c: C) = ()
f: (c: C)Unit

scala> f(5)

scala> f { println("effing") ; 5 }
effing

scala> { println("effing") ; 5 }.c
res3: Int = 42
```

build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.2"

scalacOptions ++= "-Xlint" :: "-Xprint:typer" :: Nil

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % "test"
```

Edit:

It looks like you're using Scalatest's async facility. `AsyncFlatSpec` has an implicit conversion from eager values to `Future`. `Future` has an `andThen` method that takes a `PartialFunction`.

```
[error] /home/amarki/tmp/testy/src/test/scala/CSpec.scala:41: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: PartialFunction[scala.util.Try[org.scalatest.compatible.Assertion],?]
[error]     } andThen cleanUp()
[error]                      ^
[warn] /home/amarki/tmp/testy/src/test/scala/CSpec.scala:27: Unused import
[warn] import FollowUp._
[warn]                 ^
[warn] one warning found
[error] one error found
```

That explains why it mattered if the parameter to your conversion was by-name. The compiler looks for by-value conversions first.

The [scaladoc](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.0/index.html#org.scalatest.AsyncFlatSpec) talks about fixtures about half-way down the long page. There are also [examples](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/release-3.0.3/examples/src/test/scala/org/scalatest/examples/fixture/asyncflatspec/sharing/ExampleSpec.scala).

They suggest:

```
trait Resourceful { _: fixture.AsyncFlatSpec with Cleaner =>

  type FixtureParam = String

  def withFixture(test: OneArgAsyncTest): FutureOutcome = { 
    complete {
      withFixture(test.toNoArgAsyncTest("hello, world"))
    } lastly {
      cleanUp()
    }
  }
}

class CSpec extends fixture.AsyncFlatSpec with Resourceful with Cleaner {
  "An eager zero size Set" should "have size 0" in { () =>
    {
      println("test one...")
      Set.empty.isEmpty shouldBe true
    } 
  }

  "An empty Set" should "have size 0" in { s =>
    Future {
      println(s"testing $s...")
      Set.empty.isEmpty shouldBe true
    } 
  }
}
```

where throwing in `lastly` fails the test.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of this answer. Since you've added a comment you should've seen that comment by OP that "_I got where the problem was. I renamed "andThen" to "followWith" and then it compiles and works as expected_".

Comment: @SergGr The OP did not demonstrate the error, and my attempt to reproduce works. Maybe there are other types/implicits in play, but "change the name" is not satisfying. The example at bottom addresses the gotcha with by-name implicits.

Comment: Thanks, som-snytt. For me it was useful to learn about Xlint option which I had not experience with earlier. Regarding erroneous message I did show the compiler error output in the answer original description.